# Linphone-android compilation error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am compiling linphone for android.i have set ndk and sdk paths.and installed pre-requisites.i also have **32-bit** libs in my **ubuntu12.04-64-bits**.But when i '`make`' the source code.it gives me '`sqlite.3h`' file not found.

it is my log
In file included from

```
jni/..//submodules/linphone/build/android/../../coreapi/account_creator.c:21:0:
jni/..//submodules/linphone/build/android/../../coreapi/private.h:55:21: fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
 #include "sqlite3.h"
                     ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/linphone/account_creator.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully able to compile linphone-android on ubuntu 12.04lts 64-bits.Problem solved by downloading arm-2009q3(consists of arm libraries and executables)and export its bin path in bash file(i.e. export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/arm-2009q3/bin).